# Animate filling progress bar using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on building a resume that I can deploy to a server. I'm using Python's Django web development framework to develop it, but I don't think that is impacting my current issue. I'm listing out the technical skills that I have as a progress bar. I currently am able to get the progress bar to display, but I would like it to be animated. So, when the page is reloaded I want the progress bar to appear empty, then over a a few seconds, I want it to animate over to a specified percentage width. Ideally, I would also like to see it change colors as it animates. On the left I want it to start red. As it approaches the middle, I want it to dynamically become orange, then yellow, then yellow-green and finally fully green (if it's 100% full).

I created a snippet of my project, so that you don't have to view the entire file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Resume - Brenden Price</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap & jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
      .progress-bar {
        -webkit-transition: none !important;
        transition: none !important;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
       $(".progress-bar").animate({
          width: "70%"
       }, 2500);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
       <h2>Skill Set</h2>
       <hr>
       {% for skills in skills %}
       <div class="progress mt-4">
         <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{skills.comfort}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {{skills.comfort}}%;"> {{skills.skill}}</div>
       </div>
       {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

For anyone unfamiliar with Django, any of the tags with `{% something here %}` or `{{ something here }}` are template tags used to load in information from my database. This is my current jQuery call, as shown in the head above:

```
$(".progress-bar").animate({
   width: "70%"
}, 2500);
```

In my console I'm receiving the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).animate is not a function

I also wasn't sure how to change width in the jQuery to be whatever is inserted into the `{{skills.comfort}}` call. Maybe I could try to grab the `aria-valuenow` value and plug it into the jQuery?

I'm still relatively new at this and trying to learn, so any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use jquery full version not slim build. 
possibel dublicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647190/jquery-animate-is-not-a-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animate a Bootstrap progressbar from 0 to 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976841/animate-a-bootstrap-progressbar-from-0-to-100)

Comment: @mkavici This solved the animate not worked. I managed to pull out the attribute I wanted, but because I'm assigning the width to a class, it's assigning it to all of my progress bars. So they all animate to the same width. I can't exactly give each an id, which they're being dynamically generated by my database and I don't want to have to write new JS code every time I add a new skill. Is there a way I can pull in all of the bars with that class, then loop through them to pull the aria-value now from each individual bar, assign the width, then animate to it's new assigned width?