# Progress Bar not Working in AJAX Form Output?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple ajax form. But Progress Bar doesn't work on ajax form output, it freezes. I have put an example on the page so you can see it working normally.
my goal is to be able to provide the code(progress bar) here in ajax output.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35985771/20310847

The problem here is, I believe there is a conflict/conflict between the script that checks the progress bar in the AJAX output and the ajax.  It appears then, when it finished, it disappear, but no visual progression on... I wonder what I need to do to make progress bar from Ajax Output look normal without freezing?

Form.htm

```html
<html>
<head>
    <!-- progress bar style  start -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
    .progress,
    .alert {margin: 8px;}   
    .alert {display: none;} 
    .alert-success {
        --bs-alert-color: #2c4238;
        --bs-alert-bg: #f8faff;
        --bs-alert-border-color: #768478;
        width: auto;
        max-width: max-content;
    }   
    @media screen and (max-width: 1568px) {
        .alert-success {
            width: auto;
            max-width: max-content;
        }
    }
    </style>
</head>
<!-- progress bar style  end -->

<body><br>
    <!-- form start -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
    <form class="form" action="process.php" method="POST" name="checkaddress" id="checkaddress">
    <input type="text" name="v" /> </td><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /> 
    </form>
    <!-- form end -->
    
    <!-- ajax output div is here -->
    <div class="done"></div>
    
    <!-- Here is the progress code I want to reflect in the ajax output. start -->
    <br>====================================
    <br> Example: normally this code(progress bar) works below. but it doesn't work when I call the code with ajax. freezes as above.
    <br>
    <div class='progress col-md-7 ps-0 pe-0'>
        <div class='progress-bar' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='60' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: 60%;'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>hello xxxxx</div><br>
    <!-- end -->
    
    
    <!-- form ajax script start -->
    <script>
    $('#checkaddress').on('submit', function(e) {
        // get formdata in a variable that is passed to the ajax request
        var dataToPassToAjax = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "process.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: dataToPassToAjax,
            cache: false,
            success: function(resultHtml) {
                // add the returned data to the .done element
                $('.done').html(resultHtml).fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
        // cancel the default form submit
        return false;
    });
    </script>
    <!-- end -->
    
    <!-- progress bar script start -->
    <script>
    var $progress = $('.progress');
    var $progressBar = $('.progress-bar');
    var $alert = $('.alert');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $progressBar.css('width', '10%');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $progressBar.css('width', '30%');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $progressBar.css('width', '45%');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $progressBar.css('width', '80%');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $progressBar.css('width', '90%');
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $progressBar.css('width', '95%');
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $progressBar.css('width', '98%');
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    $progressBar.css('width', '99%');
                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                        $progressBar.css('width', '100%');
                                        setTimeout(function() {
                                            $progress.css('display', 'none');
                                            $alert.css('display', 'block');
                                        }, 500); // WAIT 5 milliseconds
                                    }, 500); // WAIT 5 milliseconds
                                }, 800); // WAIT 5 milliseconds
                            }, 600); // WAIT 2 seconds
                        }, 700); // WAIT 1 seconds
                    }, 900);
                }, 600); // WAIT 2 seconds
            }, 400); // WAIT 1 seconds
        }, 700); // WAIT 1 seconds
    }, 800); // WAIT 1 second
    </script>
    <!-- progress bar script end -->
</body>
</html>
```

process.php

```
<?php 
$v= $_POST['v'];
echo "<div class='progress col-md-7 ps-0 pe-0'> 
<div class='progress-bar' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='60' aria-valuemin='0' 
aria-valuemax='100' style='width: 60%;'></div>  
</div>
<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>hello $v</div>";
?>
```